# neo4j getting from a list of labels that which is a child and which one is parent

Tags: neo4j

I have a problem in which there a number of nodes A,B,C,D
where

```
B-->A
C-->B
D-->B
```

and the relation between them is children.

Now I want to query Neo4j to find that from a list of labels (B,C,D) which nodes exists at the bottom of the graph

I am making a bot application. In the neo4j database relations would be stored between different terms.

```
Like :dog-->:animal 
     :labra-->:dog
     :germanShepard-->:dog
```

Now If a user asks a qustion tell me about dog then i should be able to get dog label data and if the user asks tell me about labra dog then i should be able to get labra label data.I am breaking the user input into tokens and then trying to find which label is at the bottom.

Comment: Are A,B,C,D really [labels](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-modeling/#_labels), or just "identifiers", or something else?

Comment: What do you mean "at the bottom of the graph?" Relationships are directional, but aside from that direction has no other meaning. Also, have you already looked through the [developer documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/)? It's often hard to ask good questions if you're not familiar with the basics first.

Comment: Yes A,B,C,D are label name

Comment: for example A<--B<--C so C is being considered as the last node(bottom)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the node at the root of the chain of :child relationships. Please update your description with the queries you've tried so far. And please read the documentation if you haven't already.

Comment: It looks like you're using one label per node. That doesn't really feel right to me, it looks like indexes and constraints may be useless in this kind of model. Also, just checking, for your :dog node, are you using a single :dog node that's connected to all the rest of your nodes, or do you have multiple duplicate :dog nodes?

Comment: no :dog label will be unique.

Comment: Okay, so your graph is connected, good to know. Keep in mind that since you're using unique labels per node, your lookups are going to get increasingly inefficient as your graph grows. Quick lookups are only available through indexes or unique constraints, and those require label/property combinations. Lookups using a parameter to match a label will be all node scans, not label scans. I'd encourage you to rethink your approach if you plan on this working for a large graph.

Comment: Okay i ll think about it.But how do l solve my orignal problem

Comment: Or how to find a node which is farthest from root from a given list of nodes?? e.g if A<--B<--C--D-<-E and if i want to query that from B,C,E which is farthest then how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
Match (a:Label) where not (a)<--(:Label) return a
```

(should work but I didn't test it)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, using a unique label for every single node is going to be costly in the long run, and is going to impact your lookup speed on your queries.

So, if I'm understanding your use case correctly, you're breaking up user input into tokens, and the tokens should match to nodes on the same path in your graph. You want to find the label on the "bottom" of the graph, basically a leaf node, though in your description child nodes point toward their parent. I'll assume it's a :Parent relationship from the child to the parent node.

Here's a query which might do what you want. We'll assume you pass in the list of tokens as a parameter {tokens}. Please review the developer documentation for using parameters.

```
UNWIND {tokens} as token
MATCH (n)
WHERE labels(n) = token
AND NOT ()-[:Parent]->(n)
RETURN n
```

This will ensure the nodes you return are not themselves parents of any other node.

However, if you want instead wanted to be able to return nodes even if they were parents of other nodes, then we could instead return the node that is farthest from the root node. This requires a :Root node at the root of your entire graph. For your example in your description, :Root would be the parent of :animal.

```
UNWIND {tokens} as token
MATCH (n)
WHERE labels(n) = token
MATCH (n)-[r:Parent*]->(:Root)
RETURN n
ORDER BY SIZE(r)
LIMIT 1
```

Keep in mind that this query isn't guaranteed to work when there are multiple nodes with the same distance to the :Root. For example, if "germanShepard" and "labra" were given as elements of the tokens list, only one of the corresponding nodes would be returned because of the LIMIT 1, with no guarantee of which node would be returned.